# encodeURIComponent() on WHOLE form (ajax)

Tags: ajax, forms, ajaxform, encodeuricomponent

I have a form that submits using ajax and I want to use `encodeURIComponent()` to validate?

I am not doing this on indivudal `id` and `name` tags in the form.

How would I use this function to validate the whole form instead of having to do each parts in the form - if that makes sense?

```
var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/engine/post/poll.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data: formData, //i want this encoded
            mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
            success: processJson,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false
        });
```

The var `formData` is what is holding all the stuff from the form.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up playing around with it and just added a random var above it with it encoded.

```
var encodePlease = encodeURIComponent(FormData);
var formData = new FormData(this);
```

and then using formData var in the ajax.